# InDesign: Using DataMerge (aka Mail Merge) to insert text based on boolean in Datasource (.csv)

Tags: script, mail-merge, adobe-indesign

I am preparing some wedding invites, using Adobe InDesign (CS 5.5).
I have a .csv with all the a names.
This is used with [Data Merge](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-6c3ca.html#WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-6c35a) to insert all the names.
Very simple.

Now more complex
For most guests I would like to insert, after the RSVP instructions: "*Please remember to mention if you will be bring a significant other.*" (or something to that effect)
However for some guests, this is not appropriate. (Their partners have their own invites, are included explicitly in this invite, or are recently deceased)
So I would like to add a field to my CSV, saying where or not to add this text.

Currently my only idea is to just copy and paste this text into the CSV, on all appropriate records, and then have Data merge insert it.
(and turn on deleting of blank lines, for those that don't)
But i;ve noticed there is a `Scripts` tab under `Data Merge`

Comment: A little late, but scripts are unrelated to data merge, although they can be used in conjunction with it. A scripted solution (written in Javascript) would probably make the process unnecessarily complicated unless you knew Javascript well.